# Is this dimmer compatible with four 15W LEDs lights?

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I want to install a dimmer and I don't know much about the technology involved. From what I gathered,  with LEDs they must be compatible. I did not find any such information from company, but got its tech specs:

[image]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?  Can you get us make/model number info for this dimmer?

Comment: I agree. Without details, your question is nothing more than "Can random dimmer X (few specs attached) work with random 'dimmable' LED Y?"

Comment: yes, 80 > 60, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're located somwewhere where 230V lighting circuits are common

Is says that it's compatible with LED lights that have a power factor of 0.8 or better and nor more than 80w total.

Your load is less than 80W so that's a good start, but you'll need to check the power factor of your LED lamps to confirm its suitability. power factor doesn't add, it averages. So if the LED lamps are identical they need to have power factor of 0.8 or higher.

Power factor is often written "PF"  or sometimes "cos φ"